# Building PyFFTW executable for Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, executable, python-module

Background

I am in kind of a pickle. My app depends on PyFFTW, for which an executable has only been released for Python 3.3. However, we are wanting to move to Python 3.4 now. It seems the only way forward is to build PyFFTW 3.4 executable from source rather than wait for a 3.4 release... not ideal!

Question

How do I build PyFFYW executable from source for Python 3.4?

I am told this might only take 5 minutes... I have a sneaking suspicion it may not be so simple. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got a link from the author to the new development build 0.10.0

https://bintray.com/hgomersall/generic/PyFFTW-development-builds#files